# Grok Filter on Proxy Logs

Tags: regex, proxy, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I am attempting to parse and structured a raw proxy data using GROK filter in the ELK stack and I can;t get the timestamp and user agent string in the correct format. Do refer to sample log as follows:

```
"1488852784.440 1 10.11.62.19 TCP_DENIED/403 0 GET http://xxx.xxx.com/xxx - NONE/- - BLOCK_WEBCAT_12-XXX-XXX-NONE-NONE-NONE-NONE <IW_aud,0.0,-,""-"",-,-,-,-,""-"",-,-,-,""-"",-,-,""-"",""-"",-,-,IW_aud,-,""-"",""-"",""Unknown"",""Unknown"",""-"",""-"",0.00,0,-,""-"",""-"",-,""-"",-,-,""-"",""-""> - L ""http://xxx.xxx.xxx"" 10.11.11.2 - 403 TCP_DENIED ""Streaming Audio"" - - - GET ""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"" http://xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

I am using the following filter:

```
%{NUMBER:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:request_msec:float} %{IPORHOST:src_ip} %{WORD}/%{NUMBER:response_status:int} %{NUMBER:response_size} %{WORD:http_method} (%{URIPROTO:http_proto}://)?%{IPORHOST:dst_host}(?::%{POSINT:port})?(?:%{NOTSPACE:uri_param})? %{USERNAME:user} %{WORD}/(%{IPORHOST:dst_ip}|-)%{GREEDYDATA:content_type}
```

based on http://grokconstructor.appspot.com, I am able to parse out some of the fields except the timestamp (1488852784.440) and User Agent String. I have tried different Drok default filters on the timestamp but it still shows as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Grok can't convert to a `date` datatype. For that, you need to use the `date` filter which does this exact conversion for you.

```
filter {
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", UNIX_MS ]
  }
}
```

Which will set the `@timestamp` field of the event to the parsed timestamp in the `timestamp` field.

Comment: dear sysadmin, noted and thanks! do you have any solution on the User Agent string?

Comment: @kenAu89 [The grok pattern files](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/httpd#L6) use `%{QS:agent}` to parse the user-agent in Apache logs. It will likely work here as well.

Comment: thanks again. I will try the UA, some positioning issue as I am getting the last quoted string.